# Automatically loading the classes

Tags: php

I've built "core" class that loads another classes, and I want to load automatically all the classes in spesific folder named "class", I've started to build something, but I have no idea if it's good. 
In the construct function at the core class, I'm getting an array with the class names to load. 
The construct function calls to function named _loadClasses, and in the _loadClasses function, 
I'm loading the classes by using require_once() fucntion. 
Then at the top of the page, i'm adding public variable with the name of the class. 
For example, "public $example;"
Now, what left is to create the ocject of the class, so that's what I did. 
Example of the _loadClasses method:

```
require_once("class/user.class.php");
self::$user = new User();
```

Here comes the "automat" part. 
I want the function _loadClasses to get an array, for example:

```
private function _loadClasses( $classesToLoad = array('security', 'is') );
```

and now, I'm using glob to load the classes from the folder "class", the name syntax of the classes files in the folder "class" is classname.class.php.

```
$classesArray = array(); // initialize the variable of all the web classes

    $classesFiles = glob("class/*.php"); // gets all the web classes from the folder 'class'

    foreach($classesFiles as $file) { // loop on the classes in the folder 'class'
        $filename = explode('class/', $file);
        $filename = $filename[1];
        $className = explode('.class.php', $filename);
        $className  = $className[0];

        if($className != 'index.php' || $className != 'database') {
            array_push( $classesArray, $className ); // adds the class name into the array 'classesArray'
        }
    }

    foreach( $classesArray as $className ) {
        if( in_array($className, $classesToLoad) ) {
            require_once("class/$className.class.php");
            $classLines = file( "class/$className.class.php" );
            $classNameLine = $classLines[1];
            $classNameLine = explode(' ', $classNameLine);
            $classObjectName = $classNameLine[1];
            $classObjectName = explode(" ", $classObjectName);


            self::$$classObjectName = new $classObjectName();
        }
    }
```

I need something like that, of curse it doesn't work, it's just to show you what I wanna do with an example. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use a proper autoloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular approach I'd suggest something like:

```
// Your custom class dir
define('CLASS_DIR', 'class/')

// Add your class dir to include path
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.CLASS_DIR);

// You can use this trick to make autoloader look for commonly used "My.class.php" type filenames
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');

// Use default autoload implementation
spl_autoload_register();
```

To get started there's no need to implement a parent class autoloading functionality for "core" objects since they should only be aware of their role functionality. Use php standard library.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the array "$classesToLoad", I want to load only spesific classes, or if it's null to load everything. How can I do that? thanks for helping me

Comment: Don't worry about that since the auto loader will only the classes that are actually in use. 

In you wan't to instantiate them you better do it in the constructor.

Comment: Cool, are you sure?

Comment: Sure thing I am :P

Answer (score -1):

For this purposes you can use the `__autoload()` function. It will be called when you create a new object.

```
__autoload($class)
{
    require 'dir/to/your/classes/'. $class. '.php'
}
```

You have to use one class per file and name the files the same as the class they describe.

Comment: At the very least answer it using OPs naming convention and use the spl autoloader instead.

Answer (score -1):

"it doesn't work" is not a useful diagnostic. What doesn't work? What's the error message? Which line does it fail at? Looking at the code, the first loop, though a little messy (why do you have a file named index.php in this directory? Why don't you just glob for *.class.php?) should probably work OK. But the second loop is horrible.

To start with, why load all the filenames into an array in one loop, then use a second loop to load some of them? As for reading the class file to determine the object name....words fail me. Simply name it as the filename without the .class.php

```
 $classesFiles = glob("class/*.class.php"); // gets all the web classes from the folder 'class'

foreach($classesFiles as $file) { 
     $prefix=array_shift(explode('.', basename($file)));
     if (in_array($prefix, $classestoload) 
           && !isset($this->$prefix)) {
        if (!class_exists($prefix)) {
             require($file);
        }
        $this->$prefix=new $prefix();
     }
}
```

You could use the autoloader, but this will get messy if you integrate with other code which also uses the autoloader, but in a different way.